# How to include an external JAR in a directory within the Java classpath and run the Java class?

Tags: java, classpath

I have a Java file that contains an external JAR and I want to run it. It is a simple project: https://github.com/eveningstar33/external-jar and I tested it with Java 8 and also with Java 11. The command to create the class file is `javac -cp ./lib/* HelloWorld.java` and it's working, but if I try to run the class using this command: `java -cp ./lib/*:./ HelloWorld` it doesn't work and I get this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

[image]

What should I do to run it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java -cp ./lib/* HelloWorld` to run the class.

**Update:**

If the one given above doesn't work, please try with a `""` i.e. use `java -cp "./lib/*" HelloWorld` to run the class.

**Another update (tested):**

Sorry for posting earlier solutions without testing them myself. Now, I have tested the following to be working:

```
java -cp .:lib/* HelloWorld
```

Comment: When I'm using "" I have the same error message: Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld

Comment: Thank you for help Arvind, but it's not working. Please have a look at the github project that I posted.

Comment: Hi Arvind, sorry for the delay. I'm using Windows 7, but I tested it with Git Bash, so it is a Linux command, and it is not working, but now it's working when I test it in Windows 7, with this command java -cp .;lib/* HelloWorld. Thank you very much!